# Canvas get size keep changes with different devices screen size

Tags: android, canvas, ondraw

I am trying to draw a circle on Canvas of a View, I am facing a problem that after testing the code on different screen sizes, i found that the drawing size changes although i gave the view a static width and height of 300. I expect it to have same size on all devices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is bound to happen because devices have different densities.
Try to use the following to convert to pixels/dpi.

```
private float dpFromPixels(float px)
{
    return px / this.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
}

private float pixelsFromDp(float dp)
{
    return dp * this.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
}
```

Comment: Ok basically I am happy with its size on 7" tab. how do i set it to always be that using these 2 methods. @Lazy Ninja

Comment: Use the method dpFromPixels(). I believe height = dpFromPixels(300) will do the job.

Comment: I tried it, Unfortanetly the drawing in the canvas is still small

Comment: oops I meant pixelsFromDp(), use that.

Answer (score 1):

Density is the number of pixels per square area of the screen. A device with higher density has more pixels in a square inch than a device with a lower density, so your 300x300pixels on an 5inch 1080p device will look a lot smaller than on a 5inch 720p device.